Вывести строку только из нулей или единиц с random.randrange
import random

bg=[];cncd=[];
a=random.randrange(0,2);
bg.append(a);
while len(cncd)<3:
    if not cncd:
        cncd.append(a);
    if a==cncd[0]:
        cncd.append(a);
    else:
        cncd.clear(); cncd.append(a);
print(bg);

Ожидаемый вывод:

000 или 111 - в конце мешанины из нулей и единиц.

Получаемый:

0 или 1 - и это единственные значения, без мешанины)

bd - список для всех значений, то есть в начале допустима мешанина, главное, чтобы последними были 3 подряд 0 или 1.
cncd - список вот как раз для совпадающих нулей или единиц, если новое значение равно значению, что есть в списке, то оно туда попадает, если не равно, то попадает туда после очистки списка. Так он и заполняется до длины 3-х значений.
в дальнейшем планирую вывести 10 таких строк из 0 и 1 с 3 совпадениями в конце каждой строки.

Очень запутанное задание. str(random.randrange(0, 2)) * 3 выдаст либо 000 либо 111

@АлексейР , а вы несколько раз пробовали?

Вы, наверное, хотели печатать биты до тех пор пока значение не повторится три раза подряд?
import random

for _ in range(10):
    bp = -1
    c = 0
    while c < 3:
        b = random.randrange(2)
        print(b, end='')
        if b == bp:
            c += 1
        else:
            bp = b
            c = 1
    print()


$ python bits.py
1101010110011000
111
000
10111
1101000
111
11000
0110101000
1000
00110111

$ python bits.py
1000
110100111
11001000
010110111
1101000
111
00111
0101000
010111
00111



нет, "Какое минимальное количество раз вы должны подбросить монетку, чтобы три раза подряд выпал либо орел, либо решка?"

Три раза. Меньше точно нельзя, а за три раза можно выбросить три орла или три решки. Я подозреваю, что вы хотели спросить что-то другое, но не уверен. Три раза.
